# Error in ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: vb.net

I have an error in combo box selected index changed. if I run a program combo box selected index changed executes cyclic for minimum 3 times.

```
DCNoComboBox.DataSource = Me.TableBindingSource
DCNoComboBox.DisplayMember = "ID"
```

this is the code. While clicking save button the combo box runs minimum 3 times

saving code is

```
Me.validate
Me.tbl_Table1.bindingsource.EndEdit()
Me.tbl_table1tableadapter.UpdateAll(Me.Dataset1)
```

Comment: Do you have any code for us to look at?

Comment: DCNoComboBox.DataSource = Me.TableBindingSource
 DCNoComboBox.DisplayMember = "ID"

Comment: this is the code. While clicking save button the combo box runs minimum 3 times

Comment: Edit it into the question. And where's the saving code?

Comment: The provided code is insufficient to determine the problem. You have to post full method where you bind the combobox, Save button click event and combobox selected index changed event.

Answer (score 0):

Order of assigning property must be like this.

```
DCNoComboBox.DisplayMember = "DisplayItem"
DCNoComboBox.ValueMember = "ID"
DCNoComboBox.DataSource = Me.TableBindingSource
```

Comment: DisplayItem what you mention here

Comment: Combobox having two properties DisplayMember and ValueMember. We can assign the field name in Display Member which field we want to display in combobox. and to handle the Id of that value for example `CustomerID, StaffID, etc.` can be assigned in ValueMember property.

Comment: K but the same problem is occur